# How to resolve 'trailing whitespace' error in angular2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I run angular2 application in cmd with 'npm start', There iam getting many warnings **'trailing whitespace'**. Is there any way to resolve in one shot? I have like that warnings around 2000. I want to fix it at a time. Please any one guide me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use **`Format Document`** option in visual studio code, which will wipe out all the space issue errors automatically

Do a right click on the code and you will see the option

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But Where we need do AutoFormat? In our code or any cmd we have to use? I dint understand can you please explain briefly.

Comment: right click on the code you will see the option or use Alt + Shift + F

Comment: did you check ?

Comment: Thanks. But that is format the code. But i want to resolve 'trailing whitespace' warning at a time in all file.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio code You can use Alt + ctrl + F.